# ActiveMQ dequeue not consumed messages

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm pretty new to ActiveMQ and messaging brokers. I am facing a problem and I would like to get some tips and informations from you.

So I have multiple queues, there is only one listener for every queue, everything works fine, until the connection is lost. When the connection is established, the connection between the queue and the subscriber is established as well, but the messages that weren't consumed are no longer sent after re-connection.

How can I re-send the messages that weren't consumed yet?
I am using Spring and I was looking for a configuration to make it work, but didn't get to find any and afterwards I was looking for a work-around or something, but still not able to find a solution.
Any information, solution, link sent related to my problem would be very helpful!

here is my JMSConfig class:

```
@Configuration
class JMSConfig {

    private final String BROKER_URL = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getString("broker.url");
    private final String BROKER_USERNAME = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getString("broker.username");
    private final String BROKER_PASSWORD = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getString("broker.password");

    private final long SENDER_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getLong("sender.receive.timeout");
    private final long SENDING_TIME_TO_LIVE = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getLong("sending.time.to.live");

    private final String RECEIVER_LISTENER_CONCURRENCY = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getString("receiver.listener.concurrency");

    private final boolean USE_POOLED_CONNECTION_FACTORY = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getBoolean("use.pooled.connection.factory");
    private final int POOL_MAX_CONNECTIONS = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getInt("pool.max.connections");

    private final boolean USE_TOPICS = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getBoolean("use.topics");

    private final static boolean OVERRIDE_REDELIVERY = false;

    static {
        ConfigurationManager.registerConfiguration("messaging", ConfigurationPriority.LOWEST);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        LoggerUtilities.logger().info("Registering connectionFactory");

        // Setup the JMS connection
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(BROKER_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(BROKER_PASSWORD);
        // Does not work with spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=true so we need to setup manually
        // Avoiding "This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload"
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

        if (OVERRIDE_REDELIVERY) {
            overrideRedelivery(connectionFactory);
        }

        if (USE_POOLED_CONNECTION_FACTORY) {
            // Using PooledConnectionFactory will ensure that on the ActiveMQ server does not get "Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections."
            // This setup is also found in /apache-activemq-5.15.6/conf/activemq.xml > maximumConnections
            PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(POOL_MAX_CONNECTIONS);
            return pooledConnectionFactory;
        }

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        LoggerUtilities.logger().info("Registering jmsTemplate");

        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());

        // Qos needs to be enabled when getDeliveryMode(), getPriority(), getTimeToLive() is needed
        template.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
        template.setDeliveryPersistent(false);
        template.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        template.setTimeToLive(SENDING_TIME_TO_LIVE);
        template.setReceiveTimeout(SENDER_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);

        if (USE_TOPICS) {
            template.setPubSubDomain(true);
        }

        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        LoggerUtilities.logger().info("Registering jmsListenerContainerFactory");

        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        if (USE_TOPICS) {
            factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        }

        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(RECEIVER_LISTENER_CONCURRENCY);

        factory.setErrorHandler(throwable -> {
            String exceptionMessage = "[RECEIVER] Error on the listener = " + throwable.getMessage();
            LoggerUtilities.logger().warn(exceptionMessage);
        });

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        LoggerUtilities.logger().info("Registering jacksonJmsMessageConverter");

        // Serializing message content to json
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    private void overrideRedelivery(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        LoggerUtilities.logger().info("Registering overrideRedelivery");

        // Overriding redelivery policy
        RedeliveryPolicy policy = connectionFactory.getRedeliveryPolicy();
        policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
        policy.setBackOffMultiplier(0);
        policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(false);
        policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(RedeliveryPolicy.NO_MAXIMUM_REDELIVERIES);
    }
}
```

Here are the properties:

```
spring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode= auto
spring.jms.listener.auto-startup= true
spring.jms.listener.concurrency= 3
spring.jms.listener.max-concurrency= 9
spring.jms.listener.pub-sub-domain= false
spring.jms.listener.receive-timeout=${BROKER_TIMEOUT}
spring.jms.template.delivery-mode= non_persistent
spring.jms.template.priority= 5
spring.jms.template.qos-enabled= true
spring.jms.template.receive-timeout= ${BROKER_TIMEOUT}
spring.jms.template.time-to-live= ${BROKER_TIMEOUT}
```

Comment: Is the connection lost because the broker is restarted or for some other reason?

Comment: any kind of reason, doesn't matter

Comment: I actually does matter in this case because you're sending *non-persistent* messages. These messages will not survive a broker restart and therefore will not be available to consumers when they reconnect.

Comment: oh well then just because the connection was lost for a few moments, not because of a restart

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are still messages in the queues and that the consumers were in fact reconnected and listening on those queues? If so, how did you confirm this?

Comment: Also, can you provide the values for all the config parameters you're using? I'm particularly interested in `broker.url` and `use.topics`.

Comment: here is the url of the broker tcp://localhost:61616, I don't know if I have a use.topics.

Comment: If `use.topics` is `true` that would also explain this issue as the messages would be held in non-durable subscriptions and when the connection was lost the subscription (and all the messages in it) would be removed.

Comment: FWIW you can likely use `System.out.println` to display the configuration values at runtime if you don't know what they are.

Comment: I don't know where you set `use.topics` although it's presumably also where you set `broker.url`. This is a custom property that your application is using. See `boolean USE_TOPICS = ConfigurationManager.getConfig().getBoolean("use.topics");`.

Comment: Any update here?